# Authorization Headers not included in Headers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to send a request to oxford dictionary api but i am unable to pass the autorization headers.

This is the function I wrote

```
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);

var url='https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/';
url = url+"?word_id="+encodeURIComponent(TestVar);


    word=fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: new Headers({
            'app_id': 'id',
            'app_key': 'key'

        })
    })
    word.then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(resJson){
        console.log(resJson);
    })
}
```

I cannot see it in developer tools being passed and I am getting a 403 response,

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to send them in URL parameters (query params), not the headers

**Update**
I tried it with Postman app. Headers worked for me

[image]